US Movie: Building a Saturn V model rocket
Ages ago, probably in the early 90s, I saw an American movie about a kid who meets a retired astronaut, and sets out to build a model replica of the Saturn V.
This is then launched in on of the school sport fields.
Can anyone figure out what movie it was?

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't indicate any fantasy or science fiction aspect.

@FuzzyBoots - The fact that any part of NASA is capable of building something that successfully makes it into space and back is pretty fantastical.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469263/ The Astronaut Farmer seems pretty close. It was certainly billed as Sci-fi

Science + Fiction doesn't necessarily equate to Science Fiction. If it did, Breaking Bad would be on-topic. ;)

@PM2Ring - A civilian building an ICBM is pretty out there.

The Mercury Project (AKA Rocket's Red Glare) (2000) has quite a similar theme; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncfnz42dq28

Hmm... Maybe I'm used to smaller models? Also there's no real indication that the rocket goes to space, let alone back.

@Valorum Yeah, ok. The Astronaut Farmer sounds like it could be borderline (I haven't seen it). But is the OP asking about a movie with a full-size working Saturn V replica, or just a toy scale model?

OP needs to tell us why this is on-topic (or re-ask it on Movies:SE where it would definitely be on-topic now that they've started accepting ID questions again).

On reflection, I believe this to be Beyond the Stars (1989) starring Christian Slater and Martin Sheen as a retired Apollo astronaut. The rocketry scene is here. He launches a Saturn rocket from his school playing field. The film is very firmly science fiction, hence on-topic.

@Valorum hmm, I think I  agree, having watched the movie, it does have a scene very much like the OP described, and while mostly mundane coming of age, dealing with your problems storyline, DOES have a Sci-Fi aspect to it.  Although it appears the OP has the storyline backwards, he builds the Rocket model launches it from school yard, then befriends the astronaut.

@valorum got the answer right: Beyond the Stars (1989)
Plot summary from Wikipedia:

Eric is the teenage son of a computer scientist who worked for the Apollo program, which sent the first humans to the Moon. Eric, determined to become an astronaut himself one day, befriends Paul Andrews, the thirteenth man on the Moon. Paul is avoided by other astronauts nowadays because he was very rude and distant when he returned from space. Eric slowly learns that during his excursion on the Moon Paul discovered something that he keeps as a secret.

Thank you for all the insights, I was very little at the time, so my memory is very limited and fuzzy, I basically just remember the rocket model.
